# What do the directories in GCC STL contain?

Tags: c++, gcc, std

in gcc/libstdc++-v3/, there are some subdirectories like :

```cpp
- include
- src
- bulid
 - include
 - src
```

What are differences between contents in directory build/ and outer directory?

And in directory include/, subdirectories are like :

```
- include
 - bits
 - std
 - tr1
 - tr2
```

What do the names of these directories (e.g. bits) mean?

I have scanned the GNU C document, but I found nothing about them.

Comment: `build` is not part of the sources. It is the directory you chose as build directory. The contents in it are generated during the build process. That's how most build systems work.

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3 there is no build folder. Where is it?

Comment: it's implementation details, or parts of build chain\distribution, nothing for user to be concerned of. You have to look into implementation of g++ and docs related to it (consider source code being a document TOO)

Answer (score 3):

- bits: Internal implementation of some features (cannot be included directly)
- std: Standard headers
- tr1: Technical Report 1, extentions of the C++ norm
- tr2: Technical Report 2, additionnal extentions